# Batch posting to feed

Tags: facebook, batch-file, feed

I am conducting test for a future project. I tried to rapidly post 100 - 200 test messages to a test user's feed from a server creating ~20 threads in parallel to send them as fast as possible. I got positive response to each one of those requests (including the id of the item being created in the body) but random number of those those messages does not appear on the facebook user's feed. For example it as ~40 when sending 200 in batch.

Any idea what could be causing this? It is weird especially considering that I am getting positive answer to each request.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Facebook spam detectors are filtering the messages after they get posted.  Why would you possibly need to post 200 messages in a row to a users account?  Your app would get shut down so fast.  You can use the Facebook api to create a bunch of test accounts and then try distributing the posts to several different users to simulate real usage.

Comment: Why most of them pass then? If it was a spam detector I assume it would remove most of the posted messages not just %10-20 of them and it would do so before processing those requests and does not bother processing them.

In real usage of course I won't need to post that many messages to one specific user. I'll try what you said to see if it happens in that scenario as well.

Comment: Are the messages all different?  You don't have control over what Facebook decides to show in the feed.  If you go to /postID for each post, do they exist?

Comment: Yes all messages are different and I can see missing ones via graph api explorer by using their ids. Strange...